# VI read in a command's output, and use it for search

Tags: vi

I would like to map a key to an external shell command, which would then deliver back a token to search for in vi. vi should use the command's result then to search and to jump to line containing it. How it can be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
/<C-R>=system("cmd")<CR><CR>
```

where `<C-R>= ... <CR>` will evaluate an expression and use the resulting string inline, and `system("cmd")` returns a string with the contents of running the command `cmd`.